# Maven Wont Change Artifactory Directory

Tags: maven

I've had a fair amount of help with my Maven code and I'm currently trying to have my project deploy to a project determined by a variable. Here is my Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>maven.Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Hello</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Artifactory</name>
  <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/webapp/home.html?0</url>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>parentPomLocation</id>
          <name>Artifactory</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/dev</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<parent>
  <groupId>dev</groupId>
  <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

</project>
```

So my pom first pulls the parent Pom.xml from artifactory and checks it for it's distribution management. Here is the parent Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>Artifactory</id>
        <name>Artifactory-releases</name>
        <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/${repo}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>Artifactory</id>
        <name>Artifactory-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/${repo}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

The parent Pom.xml's distribution url is determined through a variable I assign, this is the command line I run.

```
mvn deploy -D$repo=integration
```

But no matter what it always deploys to dev and not integration.

Comment: It should be `-Drepo=integration` and not `-D$repo=integration`.

Comment: I tried that and it still is deploying to the wrong area, could it be I'm setting a variable for a file that hasn't been downloaded yet?